# Wordpress gallery not showing up

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I've recently updated to Wordpress 3.5, everything works fine and the new Media Uploader looks great. However when I add an image gallery to a post or page it won't show up on the render html page, but it will still be there in the editor!

I'm using a custonized [Roots](http://www.rootstheme.com/) theme, maybe it has to do with that and not with Wordpress at all. The images are not being in stored in wp-content/uploads, but in a folder called assets on the root level, but I don't think this should be an issue since there is no problem with inserting single images into a post, only with galleries apparently.

Comment: Can you tell us where the images are not showing up? and in what way, are the images showing up in the html? are the urls wrong?

Comment: Somehow now the HTML structure of the gallery shows up in the rendered post/page, but the images are messed up: some images are missing and don't show up in the HTML structure at all and some don't even correspond to the ids given in the media uploader. The shortcode in the editor is like this: [gallery ids='227,226,225,219,217,211'] and I only see two images in the post, one of which has the right id, while the other one is wrong and is not in that list!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are dealing with a plugin or theme which does not work correctly with the new default structure. Try disabling all plugins and see if it works.
After that try switching to diffrent theme (like twentytwelve) and see if that helps.

If that doesn't help let me know.

**edit**
So it is your theme. Search the theme for `post_gallery` and `gallery_shortcode`.
Let me know what you find.

Comment: I've switched to TwentyTwelve and the gallery worked, so it is indeed a theme issue. Have to figure out what it is now.

Comment: I didn't find anything, that's probably the problem! Take a look at the [roots](http://rootstheme.com) theme on GitHub to double check.

Comment: @Omer Did you try the steps I listed above?

Comment: @janw I tried by switching the theme and it worked.. So there is something in my theme but couldn't find it... I have also posted a question regarding this